# How to slice an audio blob at a specific time?

Tags: javascript, audio, blob

I have an audio blob and I want to chop it up at a specific time.How should I do that in Javascript ?

**Example:**

```
sliceAudioBlob( audio_blob, 0, 10000 ); // Time in milliseconds [ start = 0, end = 10000 ]
```

> **Note:** I have no clue how to do that, so a little hint would be really
>   appreciated.

**Update :**

I'm trying to build a simple audio recorder, but the problem is that there are differences in time duration for each browser, some of them adds few seconds ( Firefox ) and others don't ( Chrome ). So, I came up with the idea to code a method that returns only the slice I want.

**Full HTML code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Recorder</title>
    <style>
        audio{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.start(1000)">Start</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.stop()">Stop</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mediaRecorder = null,
            chunks = [],
            max_duration = 10000;// in milliseconds.

        function onSuccess( stream ) {

            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );


            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function( event ) {
                // chunks.length is the number of recorded seconds
                // since every chunk is 1 second duration.
                if ( chunks.length < max_duration / 1000 ) {
                    chunks.push( event.data );
                } else {
                    if (mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                    }
                }
            }

            mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
                var audio = document.createElement('audio'),
                    audio_blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                        'type' : 'audio/mpeg'
                    });
                audio.controls = 'controls';
                audio.autoplay = 'autoplay';
                audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( audio_blob );
                document.body.appendChild(audio);
            };

        }

        var onError = function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(onSuccess, onError);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is doable but won't be easy: Plug your player in the web audio api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

Comment: See this nice example: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element$samples/Example?revision=1135521

Comment: @Cryptopat: I'm using the MediaRecorder API actually, and the blob I got has a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) method, but it uses bytes as parameter . Thank you so much.

Comment: update your question to show  runnable self contained minimal code so we can execute it and help answer your question ... I have done such using low level javascript binary buffer manipulations however I know nothing about MediaRecorder API and their Blob ... also be thinking about relationship between time and number of bytes, these attributes will let you calculate number of bytes needed for X seconds :  bit depth,  num of channels, sample rate

Comment: @ScottStensland I've updated the question, thank you so much.

Comment: @CryptoBird, check if the bites are in proportion to the time, if so then you calculate the bytes to be sliced for a given time

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you so much, but I've no clue how to get the bit depth in javascript, how should I do that ?

Comment: I meant to say `bytes` and not `bites`. So I would create different recordings of 10 secs, 20 secs and so on and verify of the size changes and see if size changes are proportional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to slice an Audio media like that, and this is because your file is made of more than sound signal: there are multiple segments in it, with some headers etc, which position can't be determined just by a byteLength. It is like you can't crop a jpeg image just by getting its *x* firsts bytes.

There might be ways using the Web Audio API to convert your media File to an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer), and then [slicing this AudioBuffer's raw PCM data](https://miguelmota.com/bytes/slice-audiobuffer/) as you wish before packing it back in a media File with the correct new descriptors, but I think you are facing an X-Y problem and if I got it correctly, there is a simple way to fix this X problem.

Indeed, the problem you describe is that either Chrome or Firefox doesn't produce an 10s media from your code.
But that is because you are relying on the *timeslice* argument of [MediaRecorder.start(timeslice)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start) to give you chunks of perfect time.
It won't. This argument should only be understood as **a clue** you are giving to the browser, but they may well impose their own minimum timeslice and thus not respect your argument. ([2.3[Methods].5.4](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#mediarecorder-methods)).

Instead, you'll be better using a simple `setTimeout` to trigger your recorder's `stop()` method when you want:

```js
start_btn.onclick = function() {
  mediaRecorder.start(); // we don't even need timeslice
  // now we'll get similar max duration in every browsers
  setTimeout(stopRecording, max_duration);
};
stop_btn.onclick = stopRecording;

function stopRecording() {
  if (mediaRecorder.state === "recording")
    mediaRecorder.stop();
};
```

[Here is a live example using gUM hosted on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1r1pxsgu/)

And a live snippet using a **silent stream** from the Web Audio API because StackSnippet's protection doesn't run well with gUM...

```js
var start_btn = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop_btn = document.getElementById('stop');

var mediaRecorder = null,
  chunks = [],
  max_duration = 10000; // in milliseconds.

start_btn.onclick = function() {
  mediaRecorder.start(); // we don't even need timeslice
  // now we'll get similar max duration in every browsers
  setTimeout(stopRecording, max_duration);
  this.disabled = !(stop_btn.disabled = false);
};
stop_btn.onclick = stopRecording;

function stopRecording() {
  if (mediaRecorder.state === "recording")
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  stop_btn.disabled = true;
};

function onSuccess(stream) {

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
    // simply always push here, the stop will be controlled by setTimeout
    chunks.push(event.data);
  }

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
    var audio_blob = new Blob(chunks);
    var audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(audio_blob));
    audio.controls = 'controls';
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
    // workaround https://crbug.com/642012
    audio.currentTime = 1e12;
    audio.onseeked = function() {
      audio.onseeked = null;
      console.log(audio.duration);
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    }
  };
  start_btn.disabled = false;

}

var onError = function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + err);
}

onSuccess(SilentStream());

function SilentStream() {
  var ctx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
    gain = ctx.createGain(),
    dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  gain.connect(dest);
  return dest.stream;
}
```

```html
<button id="start" disabled>start</button>
<button id="stop" disabled>stop</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your AWESOME explanation . Here is the result of the first code [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/xVcQsPS.png) .

Is there a way to add few silent chunks in order to adjust the audio duration in Chrome ? Thanks .

Comment: So, I can get the same html audio duration in Chrome as well as Firefox ( [something like this](https://i.imgur.com/QMtTRpm.png) )

Comment: Sorry I'm AFK for now (different timezones) but you should not trust the durations reported by the browsers either (moreover not the ones they tried to determine themselves on files generated by a MediaRecorder). 200ms difference is not such a big difference I would suspect anything fishy anymore. To get a better approximation of the real duration of your files, you might want to finalize them in ffmpeg which should be able to reconstruct the proper duration. Check https://crbug.com/642012 for some discussions about the subject.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by gUM ?

Comment: A workaround for these 200ms? I sincerely think you should ignore it. Moroever since you seem to be using adaptive bit rate. And "*gUM*"  here is *getUserMedia*.

Comment: Thank you a million Kaiido .

Answer (score 1):

In your line:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.start(1000)">Start</button>
```

[mediaRecorder.start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start) receive as a parameter the timeslice. The timeslice specifies the size in milliseconds of the chunks. So in order to cut your audio you should modify the chunk array that you have been creating on `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable`

E.g:
You pass 1000 as the timeslice that means that you have slices of 1 second, and you want to cut the first 2 seconds of the recording.

You just have to do something like this:

```
 mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
            //Remove first 2 seconds of the audio
            var chunksSliced = chunks.slice(2);

            var audio = document.createElement('audio'),
                // create the audio from the sliced chunk
                audio_blob = new Blob(chunksSliced, {
                    'type' : 'audio/mpeg'
                });
            audio.controls = 'controls';
            audio.autoplay = 'autoplay';
            audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( audio_blob );
            document.body.appendChild(audio);
        };

    }
```

You can reduce the size of the chunks in milliseconds if needed. Just pass different number to `start` and slice the array where you want.

To have a more specific answer you could do this for audioSlice:

```
            const TIMESLICE = 1000;
        // @param chunks Array with the audio chunks
        // @param start where to start cutting in seconds
        // @param end where to stop cutting in seconds
        function audioSlice(chunks, start, end) {
            const timeSliceToSeconds = TIMESLICE/1000;

            const startIndex = Math.round(start / timeSliceToSeconds);
            const endIndex = Math.round(end / timeSliceToSeconds);
            if (startIndex < chunks.length && endIndex < chunks.length) {
                return chunks.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
            }
            throw Error('You cannot cut this at those points');
        }
```

If you modify TIMESLICE for your value, it will calculate in which place to cut when passed in seconds

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think :

chunks.slice(2);

has the same result as :

if ( chunks.length < 2 ) {
    chunks.push( event.data );
}

Don't you think so ?

Comment: It is not exactly the same, while in my slice, you take the chunks and slice the first 2 positions. In your chunks.length < 2, your are just limiting the amount of times you will push something. So if you have and Array[10], what returns (slice is operation that mutates the original array and also returns something else) Array.slice(2) will do is return Array from positions 3 to 10. While your if condition will limit Array size to the first 2 positions

Comment: Imagine `const chunks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const slicedChunks = chunks.slices(2);`
Then slicedChunks will be [3, 4, 5] while chunks will be [1, 2]. Thats why I assign the slice somewhere

Comment: But again, my answer doesn't fit your necessities, I didnt understand that you wanted to limit the overall audio to 10s, but instead I understand that you wanted to crop those 10s that you get

Comment: My bad, I was a little bit confused, I thought that 2 represents the end argument Array.prototype.slice([begin[, end]]); . Anyway, thank you so much for your answer . Keep it up .

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect timeSliced chunks on pause, then filter these out:

```
 if(this.isPaused){
      this.deleteChunks.push(...audioChunks)
    }
    const pushChunks = _.filter(audioChunks, chunk=> _.indexOf(this.deleteChunks, chunk) > -1 ? false : true)
    console.log("audioChunks::", this.deleteChunks, pushChunks.length, audioChunks.length)
```